# Different metadata shown on same object between Force.com IDE and MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate, force.com-ide

Needed to edit picklist values for CampaignMember, so added entry via metadata using MavensMate and all works well in the Org

Viewing the same metadata in Force.com IDE, there are no `<picklistValues>` tags in the metadata XML.

What do I need to do to get Force.com IDE to match the MM behaviour?  I'll soon be forced to only use Force.com IDE at work, so would like to get consistent behaviour across both tools.

[image: MavensMate CampaignMember metadata]

[image: Force.com IDE CampaignMember metadata]

Selected metadata for this object in IDE

[image: Force.com IDE metadata selection]

Comment: Did you do a retrieve on the object in the force.com ide? Shame you are being forced into that ide. So many better options

Comment: @Eric - yes, retrieved both objects, its the contents that seem different

Comment: Are the subscriptions the same for both tools? All fields for the object?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes... can't paste images into comments, will update question with another image

Comment: It's a lot easier to read and search if you use text versions, not images.

Comment: In your force.com ide screenshot, none of those fields are picklists... Are you not getting the picklist values for LeadSource, Salutation, Status, etc.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - true, but body text then exceeds size limit, apparently

Comment: @martin - not getting any picklist values at all, based on text search for "picklistValue"

Comment: Hmm.. what's the package.xml file look like? Even if it's just getting `CampaignMember` as a `CustomObject`, the metadata api should be returning picklist values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the retrieve behavior changed in metadata api in the most recent release (version 38.0) so that you now need to specify standard picklist fields in the package.xml file as `StandardValueSet`, but it looks like the force.com ide hasn't made the update yet when they generate the package.xml file.

One solution to get the standard picklist fields would be to revert to a previous api version :

```
<version>37.0</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the accepted answer, from the docs at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm (easy to find the docs when you know what you're looking for...)

In API version 38.0 and later, the StandardValueSet type represents standard picklists. Picklists are no longer represented by fields as in earlier versions. This sample package.xml represents the Industry standard picklist as a StandardValueSet type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Industry</members>
        <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too big for a comment - package.xml from Force.com IDE version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>AssistantProgress</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordItem</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordSet</members>
        <members>EmailMessage</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>ExchangeUserMapping</members>
        <members>FeedItem</members>
        <members>ForecastingCategoryMapping</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>LinkedArticle</members>
        <members>Macro</members>
        <members>MacroAction</members>
        <members>MacroInstruction</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>Order</members>
        <members>OrderItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Pricebook2</members>
        <members>PricebookEntry</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Question</members>
        <members>Reply</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>SocialPersona</members>
        <members>SocialPost</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>StreamingChannel</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserProvisioningRequest</members>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: The api version is the same too then? Try dialing it down to 37.0 or below..

Comment: @martin I can only see API version specified on Apex classes, not the object metadata. It's the same sandbox though, so both Spring 17 EDIT - Ah, bottom of the package.xml - 38 in IDE, 36 in MM....

Comment: I meant for the package.xml file version number. I think the behavior changed in the most recent release so that you now need to specify standard picklist fields in the package.xml file, but it looks like the force.com ide hasn't made the update yet.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks @martin.  Wanna make this an answer so I can upvote/mark as accepted ?